# How do you conduct regression analysis using SPSS when there is more than one dependent variable?

Tags: regression, spss

How do you conduct a regression analysis in SPSS using 1 predictor variable (personality score) and 8 dependent variables (stigma scores to 8 different case studies)?

I have tried to use this process as seen in previous posts:

Analyze - general linear model - multivariate - list the 8 DVs as the outcome variables box and the IV (personality) in the covariates box

Although this saves me from doing 8 separate linear regressions - I cannot get full output this way.

I have clicked on the options box and selected parameter estimates but there is no checkbox for regression or R values. Does anyone know how to get the FULL output using this multivariate technique?

Answer (score 1):

The technique is called "Multivariate regression" (not to be confused with multiple regression, which is simply a regression with multiple predictors). Googling leads to [this document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476743) on IBM support site. If you have AMOS as a part of your SPSS license, you can create a structural equation model in SPSS with these variables.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have access to AMOS at the moment so will have to hold it off till then